# Find nested array by value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've searched high and low for an answer to this, but nothing.

I have a nested array and want to find it by exact value but can't seem to get it to work:

```
let rowLetters = ["A","B","C",["D","E"],"F"];

for(n=0;n<rowLetters.length;n++){
    if(rowLetters[n] === ["D","E"]){
        console.log("Found");
    }
    console.log(rowLetters[n]);
}

Console Output:

"A"
"B"
"C"
["D","E"] // <-- There it is..
"F"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't strict type check it

Comment: Can the nesting go deeper than what you show?

Comment: BTW, don't use `JSON.stringify` for this as too many answers show. That's not a sensible means of simple value comparison.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check

- if `item` is an array,
- if item has the same length as the wanted value array and
- if the values of the arrays are equal.

```js
let rowLetters = ["A", "B", "C", ["D", "E"], "F"],
    search = ["D", "E"];

for (const item of rowLetters) {
    if (Array.isArray(item) && item.length === search.length && search.every((v, i) => item[i] === v)) {
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) mixed with [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)?

```js
let rowLetters = ["A","B","C",["D","E"],"F"];

console.log(rowLetters.find(i => Array.isArray(i)))
```

You cannot compare an array to an array because you are comparing by a reference and not a value. You can however cast the value to a json string and compare, however, this requires exact order in both arrays.

```js
let rowLetters = ["A","B","C",["D","E"],"F"];

for(let i of rowLetters){
  if(JSON.stringify(i) === JSON.stringify(["D","E"])) {
    console.log("Found");
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly, I want to find it by exact value: the array ["D","E"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter with `JSON.stringify()`

```js
let data = ["A", "B", "C", ["D", "E"], "F"];


let search = data.filter(ele => JSON.stringify(ele) == JSON.stringify(["D", "E"]));


if (search.length > 0) {
  console.log("found")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#:%7E:text=The%20JSON.,a%20replacer%20array%20is%20specified.):

```js
let rowLetters = ["A","B","C",["D","E"],"F"];
let arrayToFind = JSON.stringify(["D","E"])

let nestedArray = rowLetters.find( arr => JSON.stringify(arr) === arrayToFind );
      
console.log(nestedArray);
```

A better way to check if two arrays are equal would be using [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as follows:

```js
let rowLetters = ["A","B","C",["D","E"],"F"];

const arraysAreEqual = (arr1, arr2) => {
     if(arr1.length != arr2.length) return false;
     return arr1.every( e => arr2.includes(e) );
}
const arrayToFind = ["D","E"];

let nestedArray = rowLetters.find( arr => arraysAreEqual(arr, arrayToFind) );
      
console.log(nestedArray);
```

Comment: Serializing every single value for mere value comparison just seems wrong. Serializing the unchanged target array over and over is even worse.